# Force Directed Graph, apply <line> style from nearest .on selector

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, d3.js, d3-force-directed

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-tu5wez?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts) - [stackblitz is flaky in chrome](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/162), may not show preview. I use edge with stackBlitz, also fine on chrome for mobile.

I've created this force directed graph that has multiple labels attached to paths that sit on a `<line>`.

The label turns blue when individually clicked. What I have tried to do net is change the appearance of the `<line>` style depending on which label has been clicked. Each label has its own data, so I use an attribute in the data to determine what style the line should be upon `.on` click. Demo line 292:

```
  d3.select(this).each(function(d){
    if (d.lineStyle === "Confirmed"){
      _d3.select('.link').style('stroke', '#444');
      _d3.select('.link').style('stroke-dasharray', '0');
    } else if (d.lineStyle === "Unconfirmed"){
      _d3.select('.link').style('stroke-dasharray', '8, 5');
    }
  });
```

If `lineStyle` equals "confirm" apply one style or if `lineStyle` equals "Unconfirmed" show another style.

The issue with the above is it only applies the style to one line regardless of what label you click.

**I need to find the nearest line to the label** and apply the style to that line only.

I tried using `this.parentNode` something like `_d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll('.link').style('stroke-dasharray', '8, 5');`

Is there a way I can find the nearest .link class in relation to the label maybe?

I have also seen a way to build a relationship function and call that somehow.

Comment: are you sure the stackblitz link works ? It shows a blank page

Comment: Yes 100% - Ive noticed it does not like chrome these days. Try edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, that `each` inside the listener is unnecessary, since you have just one element being clicked.

The problem is that `d3.select('.link')` will simply select the first `.link` it finds on the page, top to down. So, the behaviour you have is expected.

What you probably want is filtering a line according to the text clicked. That could be done with `parentNode`, `nextSibling` etc., but that's not possible due to the structure you created. Thus, you can do it based on data:

```
const thisLine = linkEnter.filter(e => e.index === d.index);
```

Then:

```
if (d.lineStyle === "Confirmed"){
    thisLine.style('stroke', '#444');
    thisLine.style('stroke-dasharray', '0');
} else if (d.lineStyle === "Unconfirmed"){
    thisLine.style('stroke-dasharray', '8, 5');
};
```

There's nothing in your code to revert the change, but that's trivial to do.

Here is the forked code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-6vj5yx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Great - in terms of revert the change do you mean clicking between the two labels? How would I remove the style from the previous label so that it does not overlap?

Comment: @TomRudge Yes, that's what I meant. Regarding removing the style I reckon it's better asking it as a new question, it is too complicated for a comment and too messy for editing the answer.

Comment: Another question regarding the next stage here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471730/d3-js-toggle-attributes-styles-on-a-line-element-based-on-its-label-relation