# d3.js - Toggle attributes/styles on a <line> element based on its label relation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-agcn5s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) - [stackblitz is flaky in chrome](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/162), may not show preview. I use edge with stackBlitz, also fine on chrome for mobile.

I've created this force directed graph that has multiple labels attached to paths that sit on a `<line>`. When clicking these labels it updates the style of the `<line>` that it relates to. The issue is when another label on the corresponding path/line element is clicked the previous style state is not removed.

If this was one label the structure would be different and could toggle with a `.selectall` and target the `.class` attribute. But as these labels are looped with thier own paths and lines it becomes a little trickier.

Relevant code on line 286:

```
svg.selectAll('.edgelabel').on('click', function (d) {
  // arrow function will produce this = undefined
  _d3.selectAll('.nodeText').style('fill', 'black');
  _d3.selectAll('.edgelabel').style('fill', '#999');
  _d3.select(this).style('fill', 'blue');

  const thisLine = linkEnter.filter((e) => e.index === d.index);

  if (d.lineStyle === 'Confirmed') {
    console.log('Confirmed', d.lineStyle);
    thisLine.style('stroke', '#444');
    thisLine.style('stroke-dasharray', '0');
  } else if (d.lineStyle === 'Unconfirmed') {
    console.log('Unconfirmed', d.lineStyle);
    thisLine.style('stroke-dasharray', '8, 5');
  }
});
```

If a label has the value of **confirmed** it styles the line a part, then **unconfirmed** should style its own line another way, but at the same time the **confirmed** line needs to "disappear" styled so you can no longer see it.

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-agcn5s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: You have a line element per label - is this intended ? I.e. between Red BMW and Brown Ford Cortina there are 4 lines in exactly the same location.

Comment: Yes - sort of. The way it loops through the 4 links between two nodes. If I feed just the line const new data(links rather than this.links) to be just the one line, the line does not display at all. Must be some sort of d3 thing where the edgepaths and the links need to have the same data?

Comment: If you try this `linkEnter.filter((e) => console.log(e.index, d.index));` after your `thisLine` assignment then you will see `thisLine` only has one line. It makes me think you would be better off with one line rather than multiple because you do not have to worry about 'unstyling' the lines unrelated to the selected label.

Comment: That is true and would prefer that

Comment: What line @RobinMackenzie to add that, I fail to see where that would make a difference as I'm already using that for the thisLine assignment.

Comment: Add it anywhere in click handler (e.g. just after `const thisLine = ...`). It doesn't change anything or make a difference other than reveal the challenge you raise in the question is related to there being 3 links and 10 relationships.